# How change location of the TextView depending on content

Tags: android, xml, algorithm, android-designer

I have two `TextView` side by side in a `LinearLayout` horizontally

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tx1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tx2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i want when `Tx1` text length is fill the line `Tx2` go to next line

when now we add to length of the `Tx1` , `Tx2` is going outside of the view.

how i can fix it?

Comment: you can use so called `FlowLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` for this: https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

You most likely will have to do something programmatically with the orientation using a `TextWatcher`:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // You would have to define what your max length is. 
             if(count > maxLength){
                myLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
             }

          }
        });
```